# JSON ,retrieval from string

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

So i am working on a REACT app for school and i have a problem with data passing from page to page. I have managed to send the object as a JSON string and the code for getting the string from local storage looks like this

```
let show=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("SEARCHED_SHOW"))
console.log(show)
```

and the ouput on the console looks like this

```
{"id":18,"name":"Steins;Gate","image":"nou","no_episodes":25,"description":"a new show","overall_score":0.0,"caracters":[{"id":22,"name":"Okabe","image":"none","description":"new","no_marks":0,"overall_mark":0.0,"shows":null},{"id":32,"name":"Kurisu","image":null,"description":null,"no_marks":0,"overall_mark":0.0,"shows":null}],"reviews":[],"categories":[{"id":40,"name":"SciFi","image":"none","shows":null}]}
```

My question is how can i show parts of the object on the page for example i want to show the object id and the string would give me 18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value of id by `show.id`

Comment: show.id gives me undefined in the console

Comment: @AverageSoul what gives you `console.log(show)` or `console.log(typeof show)` ? If console gives you `object` than... well, `this.id` should give you `18`

Comment: I need to know 'console.log(typeof show)'

Comment: i solved it ,it was a problem from me,sorry